# Actionscript Event KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP not working as expected on iOS / iPad

Tags: ios, actionscript-3, ipad

I am using KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP to trigger a function for each key stroke.

On Windows/Mac/Android each key up triggers the function.

However on iOS, the key up only triggers once the native blue Done button is clicked.

Does a way exist to trigger a function on each click?

I tried KEY_DOWN but it behaves the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you don't want to catch each key press (for example, a keypress on a "Shift" wouldn't change much) but catch the text changes. In this case you could add this to your input textfield:

```
_myInputText.addEventListener(TextOperationEvent.CHANGE, onInputChanged);
```

Comment: Yes, that looks like a great solution. Thanks.

Comment: In the end I used Event.CHANGE.